# Cocoa Touch, which to use: Window Template or View Template?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, view, window

I have another issue related to Views, and i've ended up here dealing with Views and Windows in general. My understanding of all the fundamentals of iPhone development has been turned upside down.

Can somebody explain, or point to a reference, the difference between these 2 templates?

Ex: My app doesnt show a Window in the Interface Builder. Should I have one? When should i have one and when should I not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is the difference between an Window XIB and an View XIB template for iPhone OS > User Interfaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729314/where-is-the-difference-between-an-window-xib-and-an-view-xib-template-for-iphone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Window-based Application` template provides just an application delegate and a window.

A `View-based application` will start you off with an application delegate and a window, as well as a view.

Your application doesn't show a Window because the view that you are (most likely) viewing and editing now is loaded by the Window, which is in a separate XIB.

Comment: So in a View Template, the window exists, but doesnt show up in the Interface Builder?

Comment: For my View-based applications, my `UIWindow` element is contained in the `MainWindow.xib` file.

Comment: Ah yes. I noticed i do have a MainWindow.xib which indeed has the Window object as well as the ViewController for the view. So what is the pt of having a Window template? Doesnt all apps have to have a Window and at least 1 View?

Comment: Yes, but that view can be either a `UIView`, `MKMapView`, `UIWebView`, etc.